# Copy row value from sheet1 to sheet2 column

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sheet1.activate
Sheet1.range("C4：H4").select
selection.copy
Sheets("Sheet2").select
Range("C4:C9").pasteSpecial
```

This is the code I tried which does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing the last 2 lines of code with the below. You will require the Transpose parameter.

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C4:C9").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
Sheets("Sheet2").activate
```

Comment: it works , but why it will nevigate to sheet1 after copying?

Comment: because the first line of code where sheet1 was activated still stands. if you'd like to move to sheet2, you can add another line of code like in the edited post to activate sheet2

Answer (score 1):

first please avoid using Select Statements, try simply this

```
Sheets(1).Range("C4:H4").Copy
Sheets(2).Range("C4:H4").PasteSpecial
```

its unnecessary to use select and Range.

If you simply copy then you also dont have to activate your Destination Sheet.

For further information see the documentation of the PasteSpecial Method:
[VBA PasteSpecial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-en/office/vba/api/excel.range.pastespecial)

Comment: is that possible to copy a row value to a colume value? for example copy from sheet 1 C4:H4 to sheet2 C4:C9

Comment: the pasteSpecial Method hast a Transpose declaration:
`Sheets(2).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True`